# Replace first line of a file using sed command in a python script

Tags: python, sed

I am working on a python script that needs to replace first line of a file with another.

`#!/bin/bash` with `#!/usr/bin/custom_shell`

Only first line has to change, I tried using sed command in subprocess.call, but was not successfull, could someone please suggest a cute and simple way to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about _a cute and simple way_ to do something without giving any information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
sed -e '1s:#!/bin/bash:#!/usr/bin/custom_shell:' yourfile.py
```

This will write the placement to the standard output. To save over the file with the replaced text instead, use the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '' -e '1s:#!/bin/bash:#!/usr/bin/custom_shell:' yourfile.py
```

Comment: I get `bash: !/usr/bin/python3\.9: event not found`, seems that the `!` is interpreted specially by bash

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `sed` and `subprocess` at all.

```
import os
replacement, shebang_line = "#!/usr/bin/custom_shell\n", ""

with open("InputFile.txt") as input_file, open("tempFile.txt") as output_file:

    # Find the first non-empty line (which is assumed to be the shebang line)
    while not shebang_line:
        shebang_line = next(input_file).strip()

    # Write the replacement line
    output_file.write(replacement)

    # Write rest of the lines from input file to output file
    map(output_file.write, input_file)

# rename the temporary file to the original input file
os.rename("tempFile.txt", "InputFile.txt")
```

Comment: This should really use a temporary file name (ie. the `tempfile` module).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use python to open the file, make the change and write it back to the file? Unless your files are too huge to hold in memory.

```
for i in files_to_change:
    with open(i,'rw') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines[lines.index("#!/bin/bash\n")] = "#!/usr/bin/custom_shell"
        f.seek(0)
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to modify files **in place**

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput("your_file_name", inplace=True):
    print("#!/usr/bin/custom_shell")
    break
```